# Django 'The current path, dict_list2.html, didn’t match any of these.'

Tags: django, django-urls

I wanna make dictionary by using Django.

I made a code like this, but it caused an error .

> Using the URLconf defined in config.urls, Django tried these URL
> patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/ [name='dict_list1'] [name='dict_list2'] [name='dict_list3']
> [name='dict_list4']
>
> The current path, dict_list2.html, didn’t match any of these.

How can I solve this problem?

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from dialect import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.csvToModel1, name='dict_list1'),
    path('', views.csvToModel2, name='dict_list2'),
    path('', views.csvToModel3, name='dict_list3'),
    path('', views.csvToModel4, name='dict_list4'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside you app directory:

```
Create a new file called urls.py and import this:

From django.urls import path
From . import views

Urlpattern = [
   path('', views.csvToModel1, name='duct_list1'),
   path('dict_list2', views.csvToModel2, name=('dict_list2'),
   """"""
]
```

Delete all these code written in your project directory inside url.py except:

```
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

Add this

```
From django.contrib import admin
From django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
       path('', include('#YourApp.urls'),
]
```